# Need to export from Folio to XML (or convert FFF to XML)

Tags: php, xml

I've looked everywhere I can for a solution to this problem to no avail, so I could really do with some help from you guys. We have a stack of data in a bunch of [Folio Views](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folio_Corporation) infobases that I am trying to extract in order to stick into our MySQL database. It's legacy software that is no longer supported so there isn't any kind of official place I can go for support unfortunately. Folio exports into a few different formats, the most structured of which is Folio Flat Format (.fff) - the other export options are .txt, .rtf, etc. (i.e. not ideal). This is a proprietary format that is not used anywhere else, but it does vaguely resemble XML.

What I am wanting to do is convert these FFF files to XML files so I can work with them properly. My ultimate goal is to get the data into MySQL so I figure XML is the best path to take, but if anyone has a different/better solution then that would be great.

I am working in PHP so ideally I would like to find a PHP library that can do this for me, but I'm open to anything.

Comment: Do you have a documentation of the FFF fileformat somewhere?

Comment: I can't find documentation anywhere. [This site](http://folioreference.com/) has a bit of info about the format, but not a lot. I have contacted the owner of that site to see if they can help, but no response so far.

Comment: I wrote a java converter that takes it to perfect, lossless XHTML. Until I acquire distribution rights, however, only I can run the conversion. E-mail me at support@imageresizing.net if you're interested.

Comment: Update - Folio->XML converter is now open-source at https://github.com/imazen/folioxml

Comment: Thanks! If only I had that library 3 years ago...